# Using Uglify.js to compress multiple files, into separate files

Tags: javascript, compression, minify, uglifyjs

I'm trying to compress/minify all my JS files at once with Uglify.js.

Adding more than one file is not a problem, but is there a way to create separate files for all the input files?

Thanks in advance!